# How Could I Make My Enemy Bullets Attacks better?

Tags: python, pygame

so recently I had help making bullets attack the player but it is only hitting the player y axis like if my player jumps the bullets wont attack it only moves with the y axis

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/281245cd737846920325cc619da9b2e6) like if I am in the middle it wont attack the player at all it will just attack the y axis

> > my point is how could I make it attack smoothier at any direction the player goes even if the player jumps

this here is where the bullets append from the enemys gun and attack the player ones he is close to them but its not attack will

```
            for shootss in shootsright:

                if shootss.x < 500 and shootss.x > 0:

                    if enemyshoots1.x < playerman.x:

                        shootss.x +=  5
                    else:
                        shootss.x -= 5
                else:
                    shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))
                if shootss.y < 500 and shootss.y >0:
                    if enemyshoots1.y < playerman.y:
                        shootss.y += 5
                    else:
                        shootss.y -= 5
                else:
                    shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))

            if len(shootsright) < 1:
                    shootsright.append(Bools(round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107),round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50),(0,0,0)))
                # projectile class for each of the bullets
```

Comment: With your description and video I still have no idea what you want or what is happening.  I see your health bar become more red at some point, and triangles falling from the ceiling, and hearts floating around.

Comment: what I want is a smoothier way for my enemy bullets to attack the player here is a better video to explain [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/4378a35d8ef7fda834174430c25d3aef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to decode what you are trying to do or what you have written, this is not minimal code that anyone can run themselves, and it took two videos for me to even figure out that your "bullets" are the hearts zig zagging around.

That being said,

I think you are asking for your bullets to head directly towards the player (curve) instead of zig zagging around on lines with slope 1 (like the legs of an `X`).

Guessing at the variables and context, you seem to have a few bugs, in particular:

- you look at the position of the shooter (not the bullet) when determining which way you want them to go.
- you can crash your program if the bullet flies out the 0,0 or 500,500 corner

To make the bullets curve towards the player, you need to use some basic trig instead of +/- 5 px.  The corresponding bullet speed is `5 sqrt(2)` for your current implementation, so lets keep that.  You want to figure out the total distance and direction to your player, and scale that total distance down by the speed, e.g.:

```
# Speed same as a vector of (5, 5)
speed = 5 * sqrt(2)

# Initial coordinates
px, py, bx, by = player_x, player_y, bullet_x, bullet_y

# Delta vector from bullet to player
dx, dy = px - bx, py - by

# Scaled vector (desired direction of bullet)
distance = sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) or 1  # Shouldn't be 0
sx, sy = float(dx) / distance, float(dy) / distance

# Find new bullet coordinates
new_bx, new_by = bx + sx, by + sy
```

If you need to use integer coordinates you may need to round, but it will probably look weird.

Here's a function to help simplify logic for you:

```
from math import sqrt

# Speed same as a vector of (5, 5)
BULLET_SPEED = 5 * sqrt(2)


def move_bullet(bullet, player):
    '''
    Assumes bullet and player have .x and .y attributes
    and bullet.x/y can be modified
    '''
    # Delta vector from bullet to player
    dx = player.x - bullet.x
    dy = player.y - bullet.x

    # Unit vector (desired direction of bullet)
    # 'or 1' is to avoid division by 0 in case collision fails
    distance = sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) or 1
    ux, uy = float(dx) / distance, float(dy) / distance

    # Move up to speed (don't go past player)
    length = min(BULLET_SPEED, distance)

    # Find new bullet coordinates
    bullet.x += length * ux
    bullet.y += length * uy
```

then you can invoke this above as

```
if not (0 <= shootss.x <= 500 and 0 <= shootss.y <= 500):
    <pop bullet logic>
    continue
move_bullet(shootss, playerman)
```

Comment: [script](https://pastebin.com/weS8ArZj) do I need to change anything on my bullet class? I am a little confused on how I could do that to my code also the the p's are the player and the b's  I am confused on how to write that as my code

Comment: I believe `shootss.x` is `bx` above, `playerman.y` is `py`, etc.  You can translate it into whatever makes sense though

Comment: I am confused on how I should write the code I am still learning python this is what I did but idk if I am doing it right or wrong [script](https://pastebin.com/YW9bbR4r)

Comment: Yeah, that's a little wrong ;).  You literally want the syntax I have above, it is not pseudocode.  When you write something like `a and b = c and d` it shouldn't even parse.  `a, b = c, d` is similar to `tmp_a = c; tmp_b = d; a = tmp_a; b = tmp_b`, it assigns both at the same time

Comment: Added an example so you can see how you might use a function

Comment: I see the example bu i am still a little confused... do I put the def under my bullet class for the enemy or do put it alone and how would I call the function later?

Comment: You'll need to play around a bit with the language.  Try starting with something standalone with print functions instead to see if you can figure out how functions work.

Comment: I know how the def funtions work and I could do other stuff with it but I am just getting started with making enemy shoot at the player

Comment: I have something similar my player shoots at what ever position the mouse is at when its clicked I wonder how I could change it to make my enemy shoot the player but without clicking [script](https://pastebin.com/ixM0LWXV)

Comment: Yes, that is the same logic.  You could e.g. add a method to your bullet class called "aim_at" that takes another object and points directly towards it (note that unless there is a time limit you will never be able to get rid of the bullets chasing you) and call that before it moves.  You could even make a "curve_towards" that changes the angle slightly instead of perfectly (so it wouldn't chase forever if you dodge)